# "Hidden" options when booting (with GRUB)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, laptop

I have a laptop and I'd like to install Ubuntu and Windows on it.  I would however like to *hide* the fact that it's dual-boot and got Ubuntu installed as well.

Is it possible to set-up GRUB in such a way that if I press a **specific key combination** (eg. Shift-M) during a **very brief period** (maybe 3 seconds or so) at boot-up, then (and *only* then) I would get a menu letting me choose between Windows and Ubuntu - else it would boot Windows.  Is it also possible to get GRUB to **give a little tell** - eg. a flashing cursor or the appearance of a letter in one corner - so I'd know when I could press the key(s) to get the menu?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard feature of GRUB. The only difference is that the key to bring up the GRUB menu is either <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

To change the settings for GRUB, bring up your favorite editor and edit the file located at `/etc/default/grub`. Using the `terminal` app, like so:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

At the top of the file, you'll see a number of settings that you can change, like so:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved        # change this line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true     # add this line
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0    #uncomment this line
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10           # change this line
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

As shown, the first two lines will save the last OS selection that you made, and then boot to the same operating system again at next boot. You'll probably need to add `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` yourself.

If you decide that you'd ALWAYS like to default to the same OS, set `GRUB_DEFAULT=n`, where `n` is the GRUB menu positional OS number *(count starts at zero)* that you'd like to boot *(ie: `GRUB_DEFAULT=3` for Windows OS)*, and you'd comment out the `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` by placing a `#` at the front of that line.

The `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` lines are the ones that you want to change.

Uncomment `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`, by removing the `#` from that line, and try with the setting =0. If you find that it's not picking up your <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys at boot time, you can increase this setting to 1-3 seconds.

Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` from the default of 10 seconds to display the menu before continuing to boot, to 0 seconds, like so: `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.

Once edited and saved, you need to update your GRUB on disk, like so:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: What's with the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET line, and should this be added?

Comment: @thomasrutter That line is already there, with either a TRUE or FALSE value.

Answer (score 0):

You find a tutorial for setting up grub at this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup)

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

You want to change the setting, to change `GRUB_DEFAULT` to point to Windows, and you want to hide the grub menu.

The grub menu should be available if you press a key very early, keep it pressed. "While GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is active, the menu can be displayed by pressing any key."

I think you will find a good combination of the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT` from the link above. Maybe you need some *trial and error* until you get everything the way you want.